# Erro String types not alowed Android Studio

Tags: android, android-xml

Estou seguindo um [tutorial](http://androidbash.com/firebase-classic-email-login-facebook-login-android/) de login no Facebook com Firebase, não irei colocar todos os arquivos pois são basicamente os do próprio tutorial.

Ao rodar o código, está aparecendo o seguinte erro:

*`String types not allowed (at 'activity_horizontal_margin' with value ").`*

E ao clicar no erro, ele vai para a linha 698 do arquivo **values.xml**:

```
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult" parent="">
```

Deveria ter algo entre as aspas?

Print do erro e de parte do código:

[image: print da tela]

Comment: Tem um highlight no `menu_main`. Suponho que o erro esteja lá?

Comment: talvez seu <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult" parent=""> deva ter um "parent" preenchido para herdar de algum lugar.

Tente um "Base.TextAppearance.AppCompa"